# :not не срабатывет при вложенном идентификаторе id

Tags: css

Помогите решить мою задачку. Необходимо чтобы при наведении курсора на label с классом checkbox он не менял цвет, тогда как остальные label меняли, при этом код html нельзя менять, только css.

```
<form id="main">
    <div class="userdata">
        <div id="username">
            <label>Блок 1</label>
        </div>
        <div id="password">
            <label>Блок 2</label>
        </div>
        <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
            <label>Блок 3</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

и css стили

```
#main {background:grey;}
label:not([class~="checkbox"]):hover {color:red}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как класс `.checkbox` навешан не на label, то и проверять нужно не его, а вышестоящий div: `div:not(.checkbox):hover>label {}` или `div:not(.checkbox)>label:hover {}` в зависимости от задачи.

```css
#main {background:grey;}
.userdata div:not(.checkbox):hover label {color:red}
```

```html
<form id="main">
    <div class="userdata">
        <div id="username">
            <label>Блок 1</label>
        </div>
        <div id="password">
            <label>Блок 2</label>
        </div>
        <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
            <label>Блок 3</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вашего `label` и так нет класса `checkbox`, только у его родителя.

```css
#main {background:grey;}
/* Ваш доработанный вариант
label:not([class~="checkbox"]):hover {color:red}

.checkbox label:hover {
color: black;}
или
*/
.userdata > div:not([class="checkbox"]) label:hover{
color: red;}
```

```html
<form id="main">
<div class="userdata">
    <div id="username">
        <label>Блок 1</label>
    </div>
    <div id="password">
        <label>Блок 2</label>
    </div>
    <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
        <label>Блок 3</label>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```